# How To update cell values with previous cell values + another cell value

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a problem with my project, on the server side, with SQL Script.
I'm trying to set up payments. 
[image: 1]

the problem is, when customer doesn't pays for current day, in `PayedAmount` there will be "0", `Status = 2`, but the Difference value must be Previous value plus `PaymentAmount` value. I can do this with 1 row, 1 credit, but I don't know how to do this with couple of customers. how to update all this values ?

sorry for my English, help me if you can

Comment: Sample data (not a screenshot) and desired results is more helpful

Comment: Is clientId like an unique account number?

Comment: im new one here, sorry. i'll post data when i get home. i'll try to explain what im asking for... this is `PaymentHistory` table, it has relation with 'Credits' table, every `CreditId` is unique, `ID` for every row is unique, when custumer pays for credit `Difference = Difference + (PaymentAmount - PayedAmount)` i get difference by Id, i'll post my code later, but when customer does not pay, there can be couple ofcustomers, i dont know how to update all them at once, i can get all id in c# code and run it in for loop, but i belive i can do this with procrdure

Answer (score 0):

look at my solution.

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Id              INT,
    CreditId        INT,
    PaymentDay      INT,
    PaymentAmount   MONEY,
    PayedAmount     MONEY,
    [Status]        INT,
    PayedOn         DATETIME,
    Different       MONEY
)

INSERT #Temp
VALUES
    (38827, 37219, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-19'), 249.2308, 100.0000, 1, CAST('2016-12-19 14:12:07' AS DATETIME), 149.2308),
    (38828, 37219, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-22'), 249.2308, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (38829, 37219, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-25'), 249.2308, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (38830, 37219, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-26'), 249.2308, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),

    (38837, 37220, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-19'), 249.2308, 100.0000, 1, CAST('2016-12-19 14:12:07' AS DATETIME), 149.2308),
    (38838, 37220, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-22'), 200, 90.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (38839, 37220, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-25'), 200, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0),
    (38840, 37220, DATEDIFF(DAY, '', '2016-12-26'), 200, 0.0000, 0, NULL, 0)

;WITH cte1
AS
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.CreditId ORDER BY t.Id) AS RowNumber, t.*
    FROM #Temp t
),
cte
AS
(
    SELECT RowNumber, Id, CreditId, PaymentAmount - PayedAmount AS Different
    FROM cte1
    WHERE RowNumber = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t.RowNumber, t.Id, t.CreditId, cte.Different + t.PaymentAmount - t.PayedAmount
    FROM cte
        JOIN cte1 t ON t.RowNumber = cte.RowNumber + 1 AND t.CreditId = cte.CreditId
    WHERE t.RowNumber > 1

)

UPDATE t
SET Different = cte.Different
FROM #Temp t
    JOIN cte ON cte.Id = t.Id

SELECT * FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```